# WinRT Combobox strange behaviour in template

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a strange problem with a combobox in a WinRT application running under Win 8 Release Preview. Here is a code snippet :

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource evtTypeRes}}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding EventTypeID, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The ListView is backed by ObservableCollection list and the items implement INotifyPropertyChanged. The problem is that when I change the value of a combobox in the screen the value is changed not only for the particular row, but every row (the setter for the property is called on every object form the collection). This is not the case with the text box. What could be the reason for this strange behavior ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post is as an answer to this question (as opposed to editing it into the question itself).  This helps keep SO clean, and removes your question from the "Unanswered" list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the purpose of the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` attribute : value `False` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer!  Now if you accept it (click the checkmark to the left of the answer) it will be removed from the Unanswered list :)